# Deep stubbing java.util.Function.apply does not work

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The following code is given:

```
@Test
void mockitoBug() {
    Function<String, List<String>> mock = mock(Function.class, Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    when(mock.apply("foo").get(1)).thenReturn("bar"); //Line 76
    assertThat(mock.apply("foo").get(1)).isEqualTo("bar");
}
```

I get a NPE, because `mock.apply("foo")` is null. Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxxxxxx.x.xx.x.xx.MyTest.mockitoBug(MyTest.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
```

Why is it happening? `Function.apply` is not final, inside `Mockito.when` it should be inside a stubbing process, where an NPE should not happen if I use deep stubbing. Do I make something wrong, or it is a Mockito bug/known limitation?

Mockito Version: 3.9.0

Comment: You are mocking a `Function` but describing an expectation about the returned `List`, which would imply mocking a `List`. Just use, e.g. `when(mock.apply("foo")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("", "bar"));` to mock the `Function` to return a `List` fulfilling the expectation that `get(1)` returns `"bar"`. But I don’t understand why people use a complicated mocking tool for achieving trivial things. What about `Function<String, List<String>> mock = whatever -> Arrays.asList("", "bar");`?

Comment: @Holger Provided case - `mock.apply("foo").get(1)`, is simple enough, that it serves greatly as **minimal, reproducible example**. Having to work with a real situation chain method call, let's say - `mock.apply("foo").get(1).getManager().getSubordinates().get(0).getSalary()`, would not be exactly minimal. While such situations are indeed rare, it does happen. Having to mock 5-6, maybe more objects, is tedious, to say the least.

Comment: @Holger - when you are using deep stubbing, often you have 3-5 values in the chain, which can be easily defined, and only if all of them match, then you will get the result. And you can stub multiple cases on the same mock. This is why I use Mockito instead of POJOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of the answer by @Chaosfire:

[ReturnsDeepStubs.answer](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blame/v4.4.0/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsDeepStubs.java#L49) has a nice explanation why null is returned in code comments:

```java
public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    GenericMetadataSupport returnTypeGenericMetadata =
            actualParameterizedType(invocation.getMock())
                    .resolveGenericReturnType(invocation.getMethod());

    Class<?> rawType = returnTypeGenericMetadata.rawType();
    if (!mockitoCore().isTypeMockable(rawType)) {
        if (invocation.getMethod().getReturnType().equals(rawType)) {
            return delegate().answer(invocation);
        } else {
            return delegate().returnValueFor(rawType);
        }
    }

    // When dealing with erased generics, we only receive the Object type as rawType. At this
    // point, there is nothing to salvage for Mockito. Instead of trying to be smart and
    // generate
    // a mock that would potentially match the return signature, instead return `null`. This
    // is valid per the CheckCast JVM instruction and is better than causing a
    // ClassCastException
    // on runtime.
    if (rawType.equals(Object.class) && !returnTypeGenericMetadata.hasRawExtraInterfaces()) {
        return null;
    }

    return deepStub(invocation, returnTypeGenericMetadata);
}
```

See also corresponding pull request: [Return null instead of causing a CCE #1612](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1612)

Comment: You have been awarded with the Bounty, since you have provided an explanation with source code references from Mockito. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the root of the problem is that you are not able to provide information about generic types. `mock()` methods work with `Class<T>` object making it very hard to provide type information. The function you want to mock is `Function<String, List<String>>`, but `Function.class` is provided. And i am not aware of a way to provide information about generics through the mockito API, not with `MockSettings` or anything else, unfortunately.

How to workaround this limitation - the `Class` parameter you provide must contain information about generic parameters. That means either:

1. empty implementation of `Function<String, List<String>>`

```
private static class MyFunc implements Function<String, List<String>> {

  @Override
  public List<String> apply(String s) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I really don't like this one. Or:

2. another interface:

```
public interface TestFunction extends Function<String, List<String>> {
}
```

I'd say that's more elegant solution.

Both mocks

```
Function<String, List<String>> mock = mock(MyFunc.class, Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

or

```
Function<String, List<String>> mock = mock(TestFunction.class, Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

will work as expected.

**Edit:**

After some digging in mockito docs i found [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#32). It makes me believe that this is the only way to provide generic information. The link is about version `3.8.0`, but the feature should be available since `1.10.0`.